# How to generate dynamic next page link in website depending upon results fetched from database?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have this project in which there is requirement of building next page button which work like explains below.
When no. of results which is fetched from database is more that six than there should appear next page button which when click open next page showing next results that is total - six.
I am using JAVA J2EE HTML CSS.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? What are you having trouble with exactly: please post the code you have so far.

Comment: What framework is your application built on? looks like you need some rich internet features such as pagination etc. If your application is using jquery - then you could consider using a jquery plugin.

Comment: My Application is based of pure Servlet and jsp. That page is Jsp page in which next button should exist. I haven't use any javascript or Jquery etc and I don't know the way to do it.